# Calculate total money saved in the bank

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here's the question.
At the beginning of a year, James deposited 2000 dollars in the bank. The annum dividend is 4%. For every subsequent beginning of the year, he will deposit another 260 dollars in the bank. Hence, derive a equation for the amount of money he get at the end of nth year. I need year. It seems like it is impossible to derive a equation. The question is under chapter sequences and series. Thank you!

Comment: Denote by $u_n$ the amount of money he gets at the end of the $n$th year. Can you express $u_{n+1}$ in terms of $u_n$?

Comment: I cannot form a general term, it is like a mix of arithmetic progression and geometric progression.

Comment: It's not impossible. Write out the sequence of operations step-by-step and you'll probably notice a pattern. Then, you can test your pattern for n years to see if it matches up to, say, an Excel spreadsheet cell calculation. Excel is wonderful for this kind of stuff. People use it all of the time for such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He starts with $a_0 = 2000$.
Then at the beggining of the next year $n \geq 1$ he will have $(what\ he\ had\ so\ far) \cdot 1.04 + 260$, this means $a_n = 1.04 a_{n-1} + 260$.

$$
a_n = 1.04 a_{n-1} + 260 \\
a_n = 1.04 (1.04 a_{n-2} + 260)  + 260 = 1.04^2 a_{n-2} + 1.04\cdot 260 + 260\\
a_n = 1.04 ( 1.04 (1.04 a_{n-3} + 260) + 260 ) + 260 = 1.04^3 a_{n-3} + 1.04^2 \cdot 260 + 1.04 \cdot 260 + 260
$$
We can conjecture that :
$$
a_n = 1.04^n \cdot 2000 + 260 \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1.04^i = 2000\cdot 1.04^n + 260 \cdot \frac{1.04^n -1}{1.04 -1}
$$
Then use induction to prove the conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

HINT....Start at the beginning and develop a pattern.

At the end of the first year, he has $$2000\times 1.04$$
At the end of the second year he has $$(2000\times1.04+260)\times1.04=2000\times1.04^2+260\times 1.04$$

If you continue in this way, and use the sum of a geometric series...

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $a_n$ the amount of money banked at the beginning of period $n$ where $2000$ is deposited at $n=0$. Let $r=0.04$ and $K=260$ is deposited at the beginning of each period.

Note that
$$a_{n+1}=(1+r)a_n+K$$
is an expression of how much money you have in the bank one-year-ahead.

Solve the recursion with initial condition $a_0=2000$.

Hint: This is an inhomogenous difference equation of order $1$, so an ansatz will probably do...

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$ denote the money we deposit in the $n$'th year and $b_n$ the money at the end of the year.

Lets look for some pattern:
First year we deposit $a_0$, so in the end of the year we have:
$b_0 = 1.04 a_0$.

Next year we see:
$b_1 = 1.04(b_0 + a_1) = 1.04^2 a_0 + 1.04 a_1$

And yet another:
$b_2  = 1.04(b_1 + a_2) = 1.04^3 a_0 + 1.04^2 a_1 + 1.04 a_2$

We can now generalize for any n (using induction for example).

$b_n = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n} 1.04^{(n-i+1)}a_i$

Plugging the number you gave us:

$b_n = 1.04^{n+1} \cdot 2000 +260 \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} 1.04^{(n-i+1)}$

Slightly rearranging:

$b_n = 1.04^{n+1} \cdot 2000 +260 \cdot 1.04^n \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{1.04}^{i}$

The last term is known as geometric series and equals:
$b_n = 1.04^{n+1} \cdot 2000 +260 \cdot 1.04^n \frac{1- (\frac{1}{1.04})^n}{1 - \frac{1}{1.04}}$

Now all that's left is some cleaning up:

$b_n = 1.04^{n+1} \cdot 2000 +270.4 \cdot \frac{1.04^n- 1}{0.04}$